# Using Setw and SetPrecision together is confusing

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
cout<<setw(8)<<setprecision(3)<<1055.1234567;
```

Wherever I compiled it, i either get an answer in scientific notation or it has got some other issues.

Could you please tell me the actual output of this, as I am not able to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: You want fixed? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed

Comment: no, just the output of the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since you want to know what the actual output is:

```
" 1.06e+3"
```

on a system where the locale(e.g. $LC_NUMERIC on linux) is set to US or GB for example (otherwise the decimal point may be a comma).

You essentially limit the output to 8 characters with setw(8) and setprecision(3) sets the decimal precision to be used to format floating-point values on output operations.

Not sure what your other issues are, but could it be that the output is not flushed (missing newline at the end) and sometimes it appears and sometimes it takes longer ?

```
cout << setw(8) << setprecision(3) << 1055.1234567 << endl;
```